# How to store available item quantity in database?

Tags: php, database, postgresql, symfony

I'm having difficulties figuring out what would be the best way to store `available_quantity` for an item in an application I'm working on. These are some of the tables I have right now:

1. `items` table, which contains basic item information:

   ```
   item_id   name
   1         Item 1
   2         Item 2
   ```
2. `inventory` table, which is used to record when an item is received in the shop and at what price:

   ```
   inventory_id  item_id quantity price
   1             1       +10       12.50
   2             1       +5        12.30
   ```
3. `orders` table which is used to record when an item is sold:

   ```
   order_id  item_id  quantity  price
   1         1        -4         12.60
   ```
4. `abc` table which is used by a specific component; the quantity here is subtracted from the total:

   ```
   abc_id   item_id   quantity
   1        1         -3
   ```
5. `def` table which is used by a specific component; the quantity here is subtracted from the total:

   ```
   def_id   item_id   quantity
   1        1         -3
   ```

Normally, one would just go though all tables and sum the quantity to find the `available_quantity` (which in this case is 5). Unfortunately, due to some complex business logic in the application this is not the best solution and in time the performance will degrade inevitably.

I'm looking for a more convenient and reliable way to store the `available_quantity` in the database that would work fast at all time. I was thinking of creating one more column in the `items` table called `available_quantity`. It would be updated by a function which is triggered upon insert/update in the other tables and add the submitted `quantity` value but I'm not sure if this won't go out of sync after some point in time. Furthermore, if I make the function do a `COUNT()` query over the tables, it would have the same effect as now.

What is considered to be best practice in such complex scenarios for storing or calculating the available quantity of an item in the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the scale of your application.  I've seen this problem solved by using redis or some other no_sql solution as a key value store and the value gets updated when related objects are inserted, updated, or deleted.  Yes you will run the risk of a desync, but if you implement it properly you'll find that the solution actually has a very high reliability rate.

However, if you don't need to deal with items on that large a scale i'd just stick with the doing all the db queries.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've decided to go with the update upon insert/update query.